# Парсинг youtube c помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Подскажите правильно направление. 
Использую Jsoup для парсинга странницы на youtube. 
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, что не могу отловить "длительность" ролика. Видео загружается после того как страница загрузилась. 
Условия таковы, что использовать Youtube API нельзя.
Спасибо.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .header("Accept-Language", "en")
                .timeout(60000)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .get();
String durationSt = doc.select("span[class='ytp-time-duration']").text();
System.out.println("длительность ролика: " + durationSt);
```

Comment: После коннекта выставить таймаут не получается? Например, самое примитивное Thread.sleep(5000) ( или сколько там загружается видео)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что указанного `span[class='ytp-time-duration']` в самом документе не существует. Он создается JavaScript, который исполняется браузером после загрузки страницы. Библиотек **JSOUP** JavaScript не выполняет и поэтому вы не сможете найти эти данные на в документе.

Вы можете:

1. Использовать Selenium - он полностью имитирует действия пользователя и выполняет JavaScript, то есть вы сможете найти именно эти данные.
2. Посмотреть как выглядит документ без запуска JavaScript и поискать эти данные в нем. Скорей всего там они выглядят примерно так

   ```
   <span class="accessible-description" id="description-id-122142">
      - Duur: 36:05.
   </span>
   ```

Comment: спасибо. Буду гуглить в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Пробую разобраться с selenium, но всё равно не выходит
пробую так:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnpKHQwJS4k");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']"));
```

Что нужно ещё сделать? Selenium ругается, что Unable to locate a node.